# How to detect a gap of certain duration in an Akka Stream?

Tags: akka-stream

I don't think it currently (Akka Stream 2.5.21) can be, and am interested in simple work-arounds, or people seeing this could be part of the Akka Stream library, itself.

My current work-around is:

```
/*
* Implement a flow that does the 'action' when there is a gap of minimum 'duration' in the stream.
*/
def onGap[T](duration: FiniteDuration, action: => Unit): Flow[T,T,NotUsed] = {
  Flow[T]
    .map(Some(_))
    .keepAlive(duration, () => { action; None })
    .collect{ case Some(x) => x }
}
```

What I'd like to see is akin to `.keepAlive`, but igniting only once per gap, and not injecting an entry to the stream.

Other approaches I considered:

- `.idleTimeout(duration)` with `Supervision.Decider`, but this would need a separate `ActorSystem` to be created.
- `GraphStage` but those always feel complex..

My use case for this is to analyse (guess) that consumption of a Kinesis stream has reached "current state" (historic values have been seen).

Would there be a better way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with igniting, but if you want to avoid injecting an entry in your stream you could use `alsoTo`

For example
`.alsoTo(Flow.apply.keepAlive(1.second, () => "alert").filter(_ == "alert").to(Sink.foreach(/* your igniting logic here */)))`

Comment: I ended up realizing that triggering something from within the Flow was the wrong thing, anyways. The message of being "ready" would fast-forward past the stream, and not be useful. Thus, I really now want to have a token injected into the stream (but just once), when the stream shows first sign of being idle. Your tip on '.alsoTo' is nice - I should get acquainted with it. :)